# PayPal DoDirectPayment PHP Email that you payed money

Tags: php, paypal

User is making direct payment on web site. After that I want send email to user that he was payed money. And I wont from PayPal to send him this kind of mail.

I send this params

$nvpstr = "&PAYMENTACTION=$payment_type&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$type&ACCT=$number&EXPDATE=".$expiration_date_month.$expiration_date_year.
"&CVV2=$verification_number&FIRSTNAME=$first_name&LASTNAME=$last_name&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state".
"&ZIP=$zip_code&COUNTRYCODE=$country_code&CURRENCYCODE=$currency_code&DESC=$username #{$user['id']} buy $total_count $h.";

What I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can control PayPal behaviour with those emails. Don't think it's possible - at least if I were a developer in PayPal I'd never allow that in the API.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal will not send an email to the buyer in response to a DoDirectPayment API call. You'd need to send one yourself.
The whole point of a service such as DoDirectPayment is that it can run in the background, with the buyer oblivious to the fact that you're using PayPal, Authorize.net, Stripe or any other payment provider.